# Piping of stream from wget to tar, and extracting it to a specific location failed

Tags: pipe, tar, wget

I try to pipe a stream from wget to tar and extracting it to a specific location.
The file is downloaded by wget but not extracted as desired with tar:

```
war="/var/www/html"
domain="example.com"
downloaded_file="https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz"
wget -P "${war}" "${downloaded_file}" | tar -xzvf ${downloaded_file} --transform="s,^${downloaded_file},${domain},"
```

`set -x` error:

> tar: unrecognized option:
>   
>   `--transform=s,^https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz,example.com,'

Why piping of stream from wget to tar, and extracting it to a specific location failed?

Comment: You ask `tar` to extract a file whose name is an URL. You want `"$(basename "$downloaded_file")"` with `tar`, or something similar. Also, `tar` would have definitely given you an error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine both commands and skip writing a file by instructing `wget` to write to its standard output:

```
wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz -O - |
tar -xzvf -
```

This will cause `tar`’s output to be mixed with `wget`’s progress indicator, because it will start extracting the tarball while `wget` is still downloading it, so you may well want to adjust the output options.

You can use `tar`’s `-C` option to control where the files are extracted:

```
wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz -O - |
tar -xzvf - -C /var/www/html
```

The target directory needs to exist before the command is run, so `mkdir` it if necessary first.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the downloaded data to a file, so you're not actually piping anything to `tar`. Pipes are only useful if you want the standard output of one program to become the standard input of another. Here, you are downloading a file and then want to open it with another tool, so pipes aren't useful.

The next issue is that your `$downloaded_file` is actually a URL. So when you `tar -xzvf ${downloaded_file}` you're actually running `tar -xzvf https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz` and that will fail since that file doesn't exist (it's not a file, it's an internet address).

What you want to do is something like this:

```
war="/var/www/html"
targetUrl="https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz"
fileName="${targetUrl##*/}"
wget "$targetUrl" -O "$war/$fileName" && 
    tar -xzvf "$war/$fileName"
```

I don't see why the `-P` option of `wget` would be relevant here, nor why you would need the `--transform` from `tar`, but if you must use it, you can do:

```
war="/var/www/html"
domain="example.com"
targetUrl="https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz"
wget "$targetUrl" -O "$war/$fileName" && 
    tar -xzvf "$war/$fileName" --transform="s,^${targetUrl},${domain},"
```

I really doubt you do want these though. Why would `https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz` be part of the paths in the `mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz` archive?

Comment: Thank you; I had a mistake not to create two variables as you suggest and the `https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33` is indeed redundant in most cases and in others I need only `mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz`.

Comment: What's `##*/` in the regex there? A `#` comment would help, I believe.

Comment: @JohnDoea see https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html. The `${var##foo}` syntax means "remove the longest match for the *glob* `foo` from the front of the variable `var`".

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted; seems I had an even more basic mistake of not creating the desired directory I want to extract to with `mkdir` first, as explained in chat by Stephen Kitt. I was thinking - maybe I should technically accept no answer and just add a note in question-body that I accept both answers, because I also had the problem you clue of piping stream consolidated in file and not the stream itself.

Comment: @JohnDoea I don't mind _at all_ if you accept Stephen's answer! It's a great answer. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

`wget -qO - "https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.33/mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz" | tar -C /var/www/html zxvf -`