# tar flexibility for -f

Tags: pipe, tar, utilities, error-handling, streaming

In the following command for example, `tar -xzv` works but `tar -xzvf` fails:

```
wget ${target_url} -O - | tar -xzv --strip-components 1 -C ${web_application_root}/${domain}
```

I understand I download a data stream to STDOUT with `wget` and pipe it as STDIN to `tar` to create an (overriden) directory file with that data.
I know `tar -xzvf` fails because a data stream which wasn't stored to a file, isn't a file for the shell; so telling tar `-f` "I work with a file" destroys the operation.

I had a case of not noticing `-f` and a case I forgot I should remove it when I pipe; these cases happened likely because I almost always do use `-f` with `tar`.
Is there a version of tar, or a tweak to make tar, ignoring `-f` in case data stream wasn't stored to a file?

<sub>Related:

1. [What is the rationale for using -f in tar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529318/what-is-the-rationale-for-using-f-in-tar)

2. [tar without -f option in extraction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268273/tar-without-f-option-in-extraction)

3. [Piping of stream from wget to tar, and extracting it to a specific location failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536302/piping-of-stream-from-wget-to-tar-and-extracting-it-to-a-specific-location-fail)</sub>

Comment: 1, what does "consolidated to a file" mean?  2. No, magic Do-What-I-Mean (DWIM) technology does not exist...you're just going to have to learn to use the right commands and command-line options for the particular task at hand.  It's not as hard as you think, it just takes a little practice.

Comment: I would hate `tar` that behaves this way. `-f` requires an option-argument, this is simple and clear. "Errors" because of my mistakes don't really annoy me. Actual unexpected behavior because some tool tried to be "smart", applied its "fuzzy logic" and backfired – this would be annoying.

Comment: @cas it is my bad phrasing for "stored in a file".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I guess if and when it will be only helpful is subjective but in general I agree with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-f` doesn’t change `tar`’s behaviour with regards to streams or files or anything like that; it [specifies the name of the archive to use](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file.html).

I’m not aware of any variant of `tar` which can handle the absence of an argument to the `-f` option, nor am I aware of any reliable way to do so. As [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) says, you need to remember that `-f` always takes an argument. One way to make it less error-prone is to always separate it out; it’s easier to miss an `f` option in a sequence such as `-xzvf` than with a separate `-f`.

It’s better still to always use `-f`, with `-` if necessary; that avoids depending on the behaviour of `tar` with no `-f` option (which varies depending on compile-time options and the `TAPE` variable). One way to solve the problem is to always start with `-f -` after the actions and change `-` if appropriate.

Comment: Looks like you did not use modern `tar` implementations. `star` reads/writes from/to `stdin` since 1982 and I have seen `gtar`  binaries that have been configured to do the same.

Comment: Looks like you did not read the question or answer. Here’s a hint: `star: Missing arg for '-f' option.`

Comment: OK, but the OP wanted to use `tar` without `-f` and I did read it the way that he was interested in using `tar` without `-f`.

Comment: Not quite: the OP wanted to use `tar` *with* `-f` but without having to specify a file (“I had a case of not noticing `-f` and a case I forgot I should remove it when I pipe.”) This question arose after the OP missed a `-` at the end of a command he copied and pasted, from [another Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/536302/86440) (the mistake was discussed in now-deleted comments). Your point makes sense in light of my recommendation in the last paragraph of my answer, but only in a world where everyone uses a `tar` which defaults to stdin/stdout instead of `TAPE` or whatever...